# How to display currency symbols in blackberry application?

Tags: unicode, blackberry, fonts

i am not able to display some of the currency symbols like afghani("\u060B"), kip("\u20AD"), in blackberry application.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to pass Unicode characters as char array instead of string:

```
add(new LabelField(new char[] { '\u060B' }));
```

Also, make sure you have specific font installed